# Challenge: Is there a purely functional algorithm to calculating a set constrained permutations

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, permutation

Given a list, e.g. 'A' .. 'Z', I want the set of all permutations consisting of N elements (e.g. 5), such that no combination of 2 elements appears in more than one result.  So, once a permutation contains 'A' and 'B', no future permutation is allowed to contain those two elements, in any order or position.

And I'd like them in random order, so that every time the algorithm runs, it generates a different set.

If I were to do this imperatively, I would keep a hash table of pairs that have already been seen.  I would take in the list of remaining items, shuffle them, then iterate over them, one by one taking one item out, checking to see if adding that item to the current set would violate the constraints, and if I found one that does not, recurse until the requisite number of items have been selected.

The algorithm I have most commonly seen for array shuffling is decidedly imperative, but purely functional solutions do exist.  But what about the constraint checking?  The use of a hash table that stores each pair seen so far constitutes side-effects, and in fact the whole point of the algorithm is to have the side-effect of limiting the set of permutations to include only those that do not violate the constraint.

Am I missing something?  Is there a purely functional way to do this last part, without maintaining a hash table?

Comment: What do you mean by side effects with a hash table?  You are storing extra information, not changing it, correct?

Comment: Still unclear what are the restrictions. Please provide an example, even if with a limited alphabet and smallest subset numbers. E.g. take {A,B,C,D, E} and N=3 (so your combinations will be ABC, ABD, ABE, ACD, ACE, ADE, BCD, BCE, BDE, CDE) and provide some examples of good and flawed "sets of permutations.

Comment: random != purely functional

Comment: @Bergi: https://wiki.haskell.org/Random_shuffle

Comment: Sure, I just meant that if you want it to produce different results on every run, you have to pass a different random seed on every invocation.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Starting with {A,B,C,D,E}, and N=3, valid options are {A,B,C}, {A,D,E}.  Pairs seen so far are: {A,B}, {A,C}, {A,D},  {A,E}, {B,C}, {D,E}.  Pairings NOT seen so far are: {B,D}, and {B,E}.  However, we can't add {B,D,E} or {C,D,E} because that would be a duplication of {D,E}.

Comment: And you expect *just one* such combination? Or do you need all the sets of [ABC, ADE], [ABD, ACE], [ACD,BCE], ... etc.

Comment: @Jerry: It would seem to me that if the hash table resides outside the function, then the behavior of the function depends on something outside of its parameters, making it not purely functional.  If you pass the hash table into the function and the function modifies it, then the function has a side-effect of modifying the contents of the hash table, again making it not purely functional.  Which is why I asked: what is the "purely functional" way of doing this?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: the purpose of the randomization is so that every time, it gives me a (probably) different set of valid combinations.  I don't think I need to get every possible set of combinations that meet the criteria.  But that said, if doing so makes the problem easier to solve, I'm open to it.

Comment: "the purpose of the randomization is so that every time" Uh? Usually a DP will count/generate all of them (also usual, in the search for an optimum). Why do you need a DP for "just gimme one at random to satisfy the constraints"?

Comment: Okay, I was unclear.  I don't want just ONE group.  I want every group, with the constraint that once a pairing has been made, no other group can have the same pairing.  So while every permutation or subset would include {A,B,C}, {A,B,D}, {A,B,E}, {A,C,D}, {A,C,E}, {A,D,E} ... and so forth, the truth is that {A,B,D} duplicates {A,B}, and is therefore in violation of the constraint and must be omitted, same with {A,B,E}.

Comment: Put another way: once you have a group of N letters, keep track of every pair of letters that exist in that, and prevent any future groupings from duplicating ANY of those pairings.

Comment: Let's put some order in the terms: [ABC] is a **combination** of 3 from the original alphabet (*not* a permutation, the order is irrelevant). A **complete set of combinations** will involve the maximal number of combinations which cover the entire alphabet while still obeying your constraints (no two letter shared between combinations). The problem is *there are more than one complete sets of combinations*. With these terms, *do you want all the complete sets of combinations* or just one (possibly at random)?*

Comment: One set, at random.